# How can I use deftemplate to store results in CLIPS?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, clips

I was trying to build a template for storing some of the results I calculate, so I made this for initialization:

```
(deftemplate tempAlumne
    (slot nota-media-total)
    (slot nota-media-obligatorias)
    (slot nota-media-optativas)
    (slot nota-media-ales)
)

(deffacts tempAlumneFacts
    (tempAlumne 
        (nota-media-total -1)
        (nota-media-obligatorias -1)
        (nota-media-optativas -1)
        (nota-media-ales -1)
    )
)
```

And then I'm trying to use that structure to store values, but I need it to be accesible from many rules, so I decided to make it global. So I tried to store values like this:

```
(defrule calcula-nota-media ""
    (not calcula-nota-media ok)
    ?*tmpA* <- (tempAlumne )

    =>
    (bind ?llista_convocs (send ?*alumne* get-IConvocatoria))
    (bind ?suma 0)
    (bind ?i 0) 
    (while(< ?i (length$ ?llista_convocs)) do
        (bind ?convoc_actual (nth$ ?i ?llista_convocs))
        (bind ?suma (+ ?suma (send ?convoc_actual get-Nota)))
        (bind ?i (+ ?i 1))
    )   
    (/ )    
    (modify (?*tmpA* (nota-media-total (/ ?suma ?i))
    (assert calcula-nota-media ok)
)
```

because I want ?*tmpA* to have the initial values and then assign each one with modify (here I assign nota-media-total), but it says "[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for defrule.", so I don't know what is wrong or if I'm taking the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through the User's Guide would be helpful as it covers the basic syntax. I've corrected some of your errors:

```
(defrule calcula-nota-media ""
    (not (calcula-nota-media ok))
    ?tmpA <- (tempAlumne)
    =>
    (bind ?llista_convocs (send ?*alumne* get-IConvocatoria))
    (bind ?suma 0)
    (bind ?i 0) 
    (while(< ?i (length$ ?llista_convocs)) do
        (bind ?convoc_actual (nth$ ?i ?llista_convocs))
        (bind ?suma (+ ?suma (send ?convoc_actual get-Nota)))
        (bind ?i (+ ?i 1))
    )   
    ; (/ )  What's this for?  
    (modify ?tmpA (nota-media-total (/ ?suma ?i)))
    (assert (calcula-nota-media ok))
)
```